# Where does eclipse publish(disk location) the web project?

Tags: eclipse

When I run my web project in Eclipse, it publish the compiled class and html and jsp, etc.. to the webapps tomcat directory. But I couldn't find those files in the webapps directory of the tomcat that is set in eclipse configuration (CATALINA_HOME).

maybe it was hidden... umm no.. there aren't hidden files in the tomcat/webapps directory...

Anyone know where Eclipse copy my web project or how does eclipse to run my web projects??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web projects in Eclipse will be published to

```
[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp[X]/wtpwebapps/
```

You can find the exact target in the Run Configuration of the Server.